# Find part of a string in XML attribute id and replace part in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've the following simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map title="enter map title here" id="_6cb8995f-430f-4422-918b-3042f6eda092">
  <topicref navtitle="Source" format="dita" id="_c2a73e14-2bbc-4730-88dc-0c4c699bd66e" scope="local" href="urn:ditastudio:topicreference:a2cec9de-d8e4-413e-ab1e-165a70c68adc">
    <topicref navtitle="Reference" format="dita" id="_18a0b17b-e5f0-4314-8536-d8152399f8d6" scope="local" href="urn:ditastudio:topicreference:7d25c6cc-b195-4968-af91-cd0d269f803b" />
  </topicref>
</map>
```

I want to use XPath to change part of the href in `map//topicref/@href"`. I want to keep the `urn:ditastudio:topicreference:` part and replace everything after it with with a random string.

How do I do this in C#?

So far this is what I'm doing....

```
foreach (Object map in mapList)
{
  XmlDocument theMap = new XmlDocument();
  theMap.XmlResolver = null;
  theMap.Load(map.ToString());

  String hrefPreText = "urn:ditastudio:topicreference:";
  String xPath = "/map//topicref/@href";


  foreach (string oldKey in OldToNewID_Dict.Keys)
  {
    String newVal = OldToNewID_Dict[oldKey];
    String newID = hrefPreText + newVal;

    XmlNode node = theMap.SelectSingleNode(xPath);
    node.Attributes[0].Value = newID;

    theMap.Save(map.ToString());
  }
}
```

I can't get my head around it. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to do this for `map/topicref`, and not `map/topicref/topicref` too (in which case use : `XElement.Descendants("topicref")`):

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xdocString = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <map title="enter map title here" id="_6cb8995f-430f-4422-918b-3042f6eda092">
                      <topicref navtitle="Source" format="dita" id="_c2a73e14-2bbc-4730-88dc-0c4c699bd66e" scope="local" href="urn:ditastudio:topicreference:a2cec9de-d8e4-413e-ab1e-165a70c68adc">
                        <topicref navtitle="Reference" format="dita" id="_18a0b17b-e5f0-4314-8536-d8152399f8d6" scope="local" href="urn:ditastudio:topicreference:7d25c6cc-b195-4968-af91-cd0d269f803b" />
                      </topicref>
                    </map>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xdocString);
String hrefPreText = "urn:ditastudio:topicreference:";

foreach (var topicref in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("map/topicref"))
{
    topicref.Attribute("href").Value = hrefPreText + "something random";
}
```

If you want to try this code, make sure to escape the `"` (replace with `""`) in `xdocString`, it messed up the formatting if I did it here.

Comment: What if my xdocString is actually an object in a foreach loop? as in `foreach (Object map in mapList) { XDocument tMap = XDocument.Parse(map.ToString());}` How can I add an escape char?

Comment: you don't have to escape anything then, just do: "foreach (var topicref in tMap.XPathSelectElements("map/topicref"))"

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: "Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." and here's an example of the xml file it's trying to parse.... http://pastebucket.com/87983

Comment: that's because here : "XDocument.Parse(map.ToString());" you are trying to parse something that is not in xml format. What is maplist?